# How can we generate json report for integration tests in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, reporting, flutter-web, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

I am writing integration tests with Flutter's new integartion-test package. The tests are executing fine using flutter drive command but it does not give me any json report.
flutter test --machine is not working for integration tests.

I want to generate a json report for the executed tests. Is there any other command or any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you run your tests locally, you can try with this command:

```
flutter test -machine integration_test > report.json
```

Otherwise, on Firebase Test Lab you get a JUnit xml output file for each execution.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst looking for a solution, I found something:

Report looks like this:
[image: Picture of report]

I just use:

```
flutter test --machine > machine.log || echo 'Tests failed' <PATH/TO_TEST_CLASS>

flutter pub global run dart_dot_reporter machine.log
```

Reference:

- https://dev.to/apastuhov/make-dart-flutter-test-report-readable-2h0b