# Pretty print Flutter integration tests results

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, flutter-integration-test

Which library works well for Flutter integration_tests to print results and logs `pretty` or in HTML format? Following way I run my tests from across multiple files:

```
echo "Start integration tests"
flutter driver --target=integration_test/first_test.dart --flavor rc  --driver=test_driver/integration_driver.dart
flutter driver --target=integration_test/another_tests.dart --flavor rc  --driver=test_driver/integration_driver.dart

echo "We are done"
```

It has lots of logs containing application logs as well tests-run logs. I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70199921/1779027) `dart_dot_reporter` but it didn't work. It didn't work event for single command as well.
It could be because I'm using `flutter driver` not `flutter test`. But I need `driver` to modify permissions in app.

Is there any library which can combine results form multiple tests run via `.sh` file?